# How to navigate to another tab from TabBarView page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page HomePageScreen() and it has a TabBarView with four different pages.

```
TabBarView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    controller: _tabController,
    children: <Widget>[
        PageOneScreen(),
        PageTwoScreen(),
        PageThreeScreen(context),
        PageFourScreen(),
    ],
),
```

By default, the PageOneScreen() page shows in the HomePageScreen() and I can navigate to the other tabs quite fine.

I am trying to `Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst)` from inside a different route and when it gets to PageOneScreen(), I want to navigate to tab 2 if a certain value in savedPrefrence = 2.

I have tried `DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(1)` on PageOneScreen() but it throws an error `The method 'animateTo' was called on null.` and I think it's because I don't have any tabcontroller reference in PageOneScreen().

How can I deal with this?

Comment: i think your context is null, try pass your context from HomePageScreen. print your context from that working to navigate. then compare the context, it should be same.

Comment: I passed the controller and it's same thing. not sure the context will work, but will try it out

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined a `TabController`, use it do switch between tabs like this:

`_tabController.index = 2`;

Considering that you want to navigate from inside `PageOneScreen()`, instantiate it with the controller, so it has access to it:

`PageOneScreen(_tabController)`

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. I have added some more context to the question though